# Hair particles on hair particles

Tags: mesh, particles

I have a dandelion which has a head covered with object hair particles made of an object (seed) which also has particles on it and everything works as expected 
[image: dandelion]

But when I want to use the dandelion as an object to another particle system, seeds don't show up
[image: dandelion as particle]

If you know how can I make it work, help

Comment: Maybe the "sapling" addon (tree generator) can help you https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xmQlcAcLOaU ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nested particle systems are not allowed.

However, you can get the same basic effect by pressing the Convert button on the modifier to Make Duplicates Real.

[image: Make Duplicates Real]

Then you can tick these options in the Operator Panel:

[image: Operator Panel parameters]

And press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>J</kbd> to Join the converted particles to their parent particle object.

[image: Nested particle system workaround demonstrated]