# Collection particles not working?

Tags: objects, particles

I have a plane with hair particles on it with the render set to "Collection". I have a collection made up of the tree and leaves on it's branches. When I set the collection particles to the tree collection, it only shows the tree. Why?[image]

Comment: Probably duplication https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/55659/hair-particles-on-hair-particles

Comment: ... or here https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27818/is-it-possible-to-recursively-instance-object-particles?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: I don't think so. What I'm asking is, why doesn't it put the whole collection (tree and leaves) when I set the particle render settings as "Collection". I made it so that the leaves are no longer particles on the tree. The leaves are a separate object just put into a group with the tree.

Comment: Can you post simplified blend with that issue via https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com? But if you have leaves as particles on a tree and you want this tree (with leaves) as particle on plane - thats the issue covered by posted links. Including leaves into collection does not solve the issue of missing leaves on trees as particles, I would say.